# " ( " not valid in this position, expecting an identifier in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, create-table

Today is, 1/30/2022,  I have been following along with an #AlexTheAnalyst video.  I am on a Mac and using MySQL version 8.0.27. (The video is using windows based SQL Server Workbench) I am stuck!  I am trying to creating a temporary table function.  MySQL is not liking the # in the table name #PercentPopVaccinated as used in the video.  When I remove it and run the function/query without the # I get 0 rows returned.  I have researched on stackoverflow etc.  and I am not coming up with a solution that I understand. (Newbie here)

I have dropped the table that was created and I am starting over.

I am getting an error when creating the temp table that states MySQL is expecting an identifier after the first " ( ".  Anyone else have a similar issue?

```
Create Table #PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
continent nvarchar(255),
location nvarchar(255),
date datetime,
population numeric, 
new_vaccinations numeric,
RollingVacCount numeric
)

Insert into #PercentPopulationVaccinated
Select dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations
, SUM(cast(vac.new_vaccinations as UNSIGNED)) OVER (Partition by dea.location Order by dea.location, dea.date)
as RollingVacCount
-- (RollingVacCount/population)*100
From project_portfolio.covid_deaths dea
Join project_portfolio.covid_vaccinations vac
    On dea.location = vac.location
    and dea.date = vac.date
where dea.continent is not null
-- order by 2,3

Select *, (RollingVacCount/Population)*100
From #PercentPopulationVaccinated;
```

Comment: Could you please show your entire `CREATE TABLE` statement, along with the exact error that MySQL is giving you.

Comment: it should be there now.  I was having trouble typing it properly.  this is my first post.

Comment: exact error reads:  " ( " is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Comment: Based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html, _without_ the `#` I'd expect your `CREATE TABLE` syntax to be acceptable. Perhaps you should try some of the example statements in the docs link and build your create table out from that

Comment: When I create the table without using the # in the table name it is acceptable.  The problem that occurs after creating the table is that it has 0 rows of data once I insert the table and do a select*.  I am following along exactly with the video but there are discrepancies with what my output is.

Comment: You need to re-write your question to make it clear that the table creation is not actually the problem, but lack of data in it, _is_ the problem.

Comment: James, I did mention all of that in my original question.  With me being new at this, I am not sure if it the table creation itself or something else causing the errors.

Comment: How are you attempting to insert rows to the table? What SQL statement(s) are you using?

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=qfyynHBFOsM&t=2569s

Comment: I am at Timestamp 1:08:57 just after creating a table function.

Comment: I'm not interested in watching a video, I'm interested in what _you_ are doing. Please provide the information requested _here_

Comment: I am at Timestamp 1:08:57 just after creating a table function.  I added the rest of the code in the original question, as is, in the video. If I remove the # from the table name I am able to get rid of the "expecting Identifier" error and create the table but after inserting running a select* I get "0 row(s) returned" with no data.  This is not occurring in the video.  I am stuck.

Comment: The video information is there for reference.  If you do not want to watch it that is ok.  I added all of the code above into the original question.  So I have tried running with the #table name and with the # in the table.  The table is created when removing the #

Comment: Now that the table is created I get a warning about using nvarchar type which is fine because it is only a warning for future changes.  Once I run the INSERT INTO function I get the error code:  1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value:" So I will research this next and take it one step at a time. Thank You.

Comment: I think the 1292 error is addressed in the first comment that I see on the video. They say they got an overflow and had to change the type to bigint in SQL Server. I do not know what the equivalent solution would be in MySQL however.

Comment: @SarahAMangrum I would suggest you move away from the video you quote as stated above, this is for SQL Server which has nuance differences to MySQL, I would suggest digging around and finding a fairly well acclaimed *MySQL* tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: Also from what I've seen of the video (a few minutes) the author shows several MySQL bad practises, while I'm unfamiliar with  SQL Server, I would expect these may be bad practise (or at least, not best practise) for SQL Server as well ( such as [using keywords as column names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), not encasing column or table names in backticks, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

So I'd say the underlying problem is that you are watching a video tutorial that is using SQL Server, but you are using MySQL. There are many similarities, but it is not going to be an exact match. For instance, the # sign creates a temporary table in Sql Server, but the # is not valid in MySQL. If you want to use a different database service than the tutorial you are watching is for, you are going to have to translate some concepts for yourself.

Another commenter already posted this link, which indicates the syntax for creating temp tables in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-temporary-tables